# How to merge small polygons with neighbor polygons using GeoPandas and pysal

Tags: geopandas, pysal

I want to merge small polygons based on their area,etc. with adjacent neighbor polygons. For instance, we want to merge all countries in an iterative way to have a world map in which all small countries merge with neighbors and no countries smaller than the threshold area don't exist. How can I do this using pysal and GeoPandas?

```py
import geopandas, numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from esda import topo
from libpysal import weights
earth = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
wm=earth.to_crs('epsg:3395')
wm["area"] = wm['geometry'].area/ 10**6
wm=wm.to_crs('epsg:4326')
wm.sort_values('area', ascending=False)
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,6))
wm.plot('area', ax=ax,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("viridis"),vmin=5660,vmax=80000)
```